# for loop using ggplot for longitudinal data

Tags: html, r, ggplot2, longtext

I am trying to visualize my longtudinal data by graphs using `ggplot` through `for` loop.

```
for(i in colnames(dat_longC)[c(3,5:10,14,17:19,30:39)]){
print(ggplot(dat_longC, aes(x = exam, y = i, group = zz_nr))+ geom_point()+  
  geom_line() + xlab("Examination") + ylab(i))}
}
```

when I use the `ggplot` command in a `for` loop, I only get a line extending between examination times. If I use the same command on a single variable, it works and gives me trajectory graphs. What do you think could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using `i` to indicate the column. That is just an index, so it does not know what you are actually trying to plot. you really want `colnames(dat_longC)[i]`. Unfortunately, that will still not work because you are using a string as a variable name, which does not work for `ggplot2`. Instead, you will likely need `!!sym(colnames(dat_longC)[i])`. I can't really test without your data, but here is some example code to help guide you.

```r
library(tidyverse)


map(colnames(mtcars)[2:4],
    \(x) ggplot(mtcars, aes(!!sym(x), mpg))+
      geom_point()+
      ggtitle(x))
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[3]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```r
for(i in colnames(dat_longC)[c(3,5:10,14,17:19,30:39)]){
print(ggplot(dat_longC, aes_string(x = "exam" , y = i, group = "zz_nr"))+ geom_point()+  
  geom_line() + xlab("Examination") + ylab(i))}
}
```

Thank you very much for your reply!
I just used `aes_string` and added quote to the variable names and it worked out.